# When Max(R) is Hausdorff space?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, gn.general-topology

Let $R$ be reduce commutative ring with identity (a commutative ring such that $a^n$=0 ($a\in R$) implise $a=0$) and $Max(R)$ be the set of all maximal ideals of $R$. The *hull-kernel* (or *Zariski* topology) topology on $Max(R)$ is the topology obtained by taking the collection of sets $U(a) =\{m\in Max(R) : a\not\in m\}$ or arbitrary $a\in R$ as a base for the open sets. when is $Max(R)$ with *hull-kernel* topology Hausdorff space?

Comment: This question appears to be answered here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/53647/questions-about-spectra-of-rings-of-continuous-functions